# É uma má prática fazer muita coisa dentro de um construtor? Por que?

Tags: c#, .net, construtor

Realizar processamento pesado, como consultas a um banco de dados ou consumir uma API, dentro de construtores de classe é considerado uma prática ruim? Por que?

```
public class Classe
{
    private String dados;

    public Classe()
    {
        // ...
        dados = Database.GetDados();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Seria melhor fazer dessa forma ou parecido, tirando o processamento do construtor?

```
public class Classe
{
    private String dados;

    public Classe()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Inicializar()
    {
        dados = Database.GetDados();
    }
}
```

E ao "construir":

```
public void Call()
{
    Classe x = new Classe();
    x.Inicializar();
}
```

Já ouvi de alguns professores de ensino superior falando que é uma má prática, mas não vejo motivo. O objeto não deve ser construído e suas dependências ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: O que chamamos de construtor, de certa forma, é o inicializador da instância, então definir um novo método para isso parece-me criar redundâncias no código. O que recomenda-se evitar é, por exemplo, se o construtor possuir argumentos, validá-los dentro do construtor. Para manter a atomicidade, a lógica de validação deveria estar alocada em um método com tal responsabilidade, deixando o construtor responsável por apenas chamá-lo.

Comment: Relacionada: [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530)

Comment: [Se for consensual entre o construtor e você, não vejo porque não](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMi-cv5UyTTsVGRjhnaqcBcDoy5GaKFcvy_yoMfRN41UzLBC30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"É ruim fazer muita coisa dentro de construtores?"**

Se muita coisa for coisa rápida não, defina rápida como um requisito da sua aplicação e do tempo de resposta que for satisfatório para o objeto em questão.

**"Realizar processamento pesado, como consultas no BD, dentro de construtores é considerado uma prática ruim? Por que?"**

Sim. Porque instanciar um objeto é algo corriqueiro e deveria ser rápido, geralmente evitamos operações que sabemos que são pesadas e na maioria das vezes, estão sendo feitas no construtor porque o programador tenta garantir que as coisas estarão lá depois, e geralmente ele não precisa delas no construtor. No seu exemplo, você apenas carrega a propriedade, não a usa no fluxo do construtor, então poderia deixar essa ação para o momento em que a propriedade realmente for usada.

Se você realmente tem a necessidade de realizar essa operação no durante a construção dos objetos, você deve considerar os cenários onde esse objeto será usado, porque, como você realiza algo grande no construtor, certas operações com objetos que são corriqueiras tem impacto direto na aplicação, seguem alguns exemplos.

**1 - Listagem de objetos para grids/tabelas:** é comum criamos telas onde o sistema lista (inclusive com paginação) objetos para que um usuário opere sobre eles. Como você necessariamente tem que instanciar o objeto para mostrar os dados, mesmo que seja apenas o nome e o ID, você terá um grid ridiculamente lento, consumindo memoria, banco e aplicação de forma desnecessária.

*Alternativas que podem melhorar sua vida: Lazy Load.*

**2 - Forte acoplamento:** Geralmente um objeto que tem um construtor lento é um objeto complexo, que pode precisar acessar várias fontes de dados e instanciar diversos outros objetos, logo, sua implementação deve ter cuidado com o acoplamento as classes concretas. Isso também pode fazer com que suas camadas (caso essa seja sua arquitetura) fiquem confusas.

*Alternativas que podem melhorar sua vida: Dependency Injection*

**3 - Chamadas para construção de outros objetos complexos que possuem construtores tão complexos quanto o que você está construindo.** O.o (ficou legal essa frase): Você pode acoplar um objeto que precisa ser construido chamando um segundo construtor complexo, mas, que só será usado em certas situações (parece um caso para lazy load :)) e as vezes você pode nem precisar dele.

*Alternativas que podem melhorar sua vida:  proxy object.*

Pra falar a verdade, em alguns cenários você raramente escapa do fato de ter que construir objetos pesados, mas, a maioria dos frameworks resolve isso pra você e já tem esses padrões de projeto implementados.

Se você usa Entity Framework, por exemplo, o lazy load já esta lá para você quase que nativamente. Você só precisa pedir para usar. Muitas aplicações orientadas a objetos modernas usam ORMs e isso facilita a implementação dessas técnicas porque isso acontece muito com objetos que precisam estar armazenados em bancos de dados e os programadores acabam conhecendo os padrões de projeto como um recurso do ORM, não como uma solução genérica que ele mesmo pode implementar.

Mas, isso é falta de conhecimento e não uma restrição do padrão, você poderia usar o padrão para retardar a carga de uma textura de um arquivo que vem do disco, não necessariamente do banco.

É importante ressaltar que eu respondi usando o contexto do .NET, mas, muito do que escrevi aqui é uma solução geral na maioria das plataformas de POO, Java é um otimo exemplo.

Trazendo um pouco disso tudo para o seu exemplo de código:

```
public class Classe
{
    private String dados;

    public Classe()
    {
        // ...
        dados = Database.GetDados();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Sua classe precisa conhecer a implementação concreta da classe Database (forte acoplamento, mesmo que seja somente a interface.

Sua classe necessariamente vai ao banco para carregar o atributo dados, mesmo que você não o utilize. Imagine um outro atributo nome que você usa no grid mas que é retornado no construtor, algo do tipo:

```
public class Classe
{
    private String dados;
    private String nome;    

    public Classe()
    {
        // ...
        dados = Database.GetDados();
        nome = Database.GetNome();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Neste caso, além do acoplamento, você estaria indo no banco duas vezes, mesmo que precise mostrar apenas o nome no grid/tabela/tela. Desperdicio clássico de recursos e performance. Um proxy Object/lazy load deixariam essa carga para depois, fazendo com que o objeto fosse instanciado muito mais rapido e que você so desse uma passada no banco para aquilo que realmente precisa.

**"Seria melhor fazer dessa forma ou parecido, tirando o processamento do construtor?"**

Não. Porque muitas vezes o implementador de uma classe não é o seu usuário, então você não garante que os usuários da sua classe vão chamar esse metodo, o que acaba inserindo um ponto de falha na aplicação. Outro fator importante e também conceitual é que você está apenas retardando as ações do construtor para um método secundário, mas, não existe regra de ouro, depende do que você esta fazendo.

Se possível, evite distorções dos padrões de projeto já consolidados, eles estão ai porque gente muito melhor que nós já enfrentou isso.